# Cannot Resolve Ubuntu-vnc-server?

Tags: networking, server, ssh, vnc

I'm following a tutorial (https://linuxconfig.org/vnc-server-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux) for how to set up a VNC server for remote access on a Kubuntu 18.04 machine.

Everything was going ok until I hit the part where it asks me to connect to the server using `vncviewer ubuntu-vnc-server:1` or `ssh -L 5901:127.0.0.1:5901 -N -f -l linuxconfig ubuntu-vnc-server`. Which give the following error messages

> `sarah@SciLabComp0:~$ vncviewer ubuntu-vnc-server:1

```
VNC Viewer Free Edition 4.1.1 for X - built Feb 25 2015 22:57:51
Copyright (C) 2002-2005 RealVNC Ltd.
See http://www.realvnc.com for information on VNC.

Thu Jun 21 16:40:03 2018
 main:        unable to resolve host by name: Resource temporarily 
unavailable
              (11)`
```

Or

> `sarah@SciLabComp0:~$ ssh -L 5901:127.0.0.1:5901 -N -f -l linuxconfig ubuntu-vnc-server
>   ssh: Could not resolve hostname ubuntu-vnc-server: Temporary failure in name resolution`

Running `ss -ltn` gives me

> `sarah@SciLabComp0:~$ ss -ltn
>   State       Recv-Q       Send-Q               Local Address:Port                Peer Address:Port
>
>   LISTEN      0            128                      127.0.0.1:17600                    0.0.0.0:*
>
>   LISTEN      0            128                      127.0.0.1:17603                    0.0.0.0:*
>
>   LISTEN      0            5                          0.0.0.0:5901                     0.0.0.0:*
>
>   LISTEN      0            128                        0.0.0.0:6001                     0.0.0.0:*
>
>   LISTEN      0            128                        0.0.0.0:6002                     0.0.0.0:*
>
>   LISTEN      0            128                        0.0.0.0:6003                     0.0.0.0:*
>
>   LISTEN      0            128                        0.0.0.0:6004                     0.0.0.0:*
>
>   LISTEN      0            128                        0.0.0.0:6005                     0.0.0.0:*
>
>   LISTEN      0            128                  127.0.0.53%lo:53                       0.0.0.0:*
>
>   LISTEN      0            5                        127.0.0.1:631                      0.0.0.0:*
>
>   LISTEN      0            128                        0.0.0.0:17500                    0.0.0.0:*
>
>   LISTEN      0            5                                *:6600                           *:*
>
>   LISTEN      0            5                                *:5902                           *:*
>
>   LISTEN      0            5                                *:5903                           *:*
>
>   LISTEN      0            5                                *:5904                           *:*
>
>   LISTEN      0            5                                *:5905                           *:*
>
>   LISTEN      0            50                               *:1716                           *:*
>
>   LISTEN      0            5                            [::1]:631                         [::]:*
>
>   LISTEN      0            128                           [::]:17500                       [::]:*`

How can I resolve this and connect to my server? Is the server set up improperly?

**Edit 0: ** Trying to connect to it using `vncviewer 192.168.1.20:2` gets me a strange collection of seemingly random pixels instead of a coherent image. The server asks me for a password, so I'm guessing that it is active.
[image: Pixels]

Comment: It appears that you need to substitute your hostname or ip address for `ubuntu-vnc-server`

Comment: @OrganicMarble So I get that from `ip a`. I was always kind of confused about that. Do I use the I net address or the broadcast one? That makes a lot more sense though. I was kind of confused about it.

Comment: If the machines are on the same net, try the local ip address.

Comment: @OrganicMarble It appears to work partially. I tried the local address (They're both on the same network, but the screen is all random pixels. I'll edit the question.

Comment: I can't really help more, I use vino and remmina for this task.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Is `remmina` more simple? I thought I still had to set up a VNC server to use it :D I tried it using remmina, but the same pixelated image popped up.

Comment: yes, vino is the server and remmina is a client. I don't know if they are better or worse, just the ones I know.